# Does the Technomancer's Supercharge Weapon spell work on a ship's weapon for the purposes of ship-to-ship combat?

Tags: spells, weapons, targeting, starfinder, vehicles

Does the Technomancer's [Supercharge Weapon](https://glasstopgames.com/sfrpg/rules/spell/supercharge-weapon.html) spell work on a ship's weapon for the purposes of ship-to-ship combat?

Answer (score 3):

### No, you would not be able to affect a starship weapon with that spell (or most others).

Assuming you've found some way to Touch your weapon safely while in combat maneuvers (no mean feat)...

From the [Starship Combat](https://glasstopgames.com/sfrpg/rules/starship-combat.html) section,

> Shooting Starships
>
> **Starship weapons and regular PC-level weapons work on different scales and aren’t meant to interact with each other.** If characters choose [sic] to shoot at a starship with their laser rifles (or cast a spell on it) while it is on the ground, the GM should treat the starship as an object (a particularly massive one, at that). At the GM’s discretion, **if starship weapons are ever brought to bear against buildings or people, they deal Hit Point damage equal to 10 × their listed amount of damage.** However, starship weapons are never precise enough to target a single individual (or even small group) and can, if the GM decides, be simulated as deadly hazards instead of weapon attacks.

By corollary, if a GM even allowed the spell operate on a Starship weapon (which isn't a *weapon* as the spell would be concerned), it should increase damage by 1/10 of 4d6.